# FireBase not deploying... How to upload my files?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I can't upload my files to firebase.

I'm doing this.

I created a json file and added to mydirectory:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

Then

```
cd mydirectory

firebase init

Hosting: Configure files for Firebase Hosting and (optionally) set up GitHub 
Action deploys

? What do you want to use as your public directory? public
? Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? No
? Set up automatic builds and deploys with GitHub? No
? File public/404.html already exists. Overwrite? No
i  Skipping write of public/404.html
? File public/index.html already exists. Overwrite? No
i  Skipping write of public/index.html
```

Next

```
firebase deploy
Deploy complete!
```

Still seeing this:
[image]

I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gl-qlxfTJHE but still doesn't work.

Any help?

Comment: Do you tried to answer Yes to Redirects? Second question?

Comment: Yes, still not working, any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial is old

`try command firebase deploy --only hosting`

Look this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/quickstart

Comment: Tried: "rewrite all urls to /index.html" and rewriting index.html. Then "firebase deploy --only hosting". Still not uploading my index.html